# How to do minus operation between two numbers in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

It seems that SQLite doesn't support minus operator, then how to write this query without '-'?

```
select count(ID)
from Highschooler
-
select count(name)
from (select distinct name from Highschooler);
```

Comment: I don't use SQLite, but I'd write it as `SELECT COUNT(ID) - COUNT(Distinct Name) FROM Highschooler`. Does that work for you? (SQLite supports subtraction (the minus operator) if you write the query properly. It does not accept the query you wrote because it's invalid SQL - it has nothing to do with the minus operator, but your incorrect SQL syntax.)

Comment: YES YES YES!!! It works! But why my query doesn't work??

Comment: Because your query is wrong. The SQL is not proper. I said that before. :-)

Comment: Got it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite supports the minus (subtraction) operator. The problem here is that your SQL syntax is not proper for what you're trying to do. You can't  do a `SELECT..WHERE - SELECT..WHERE` in the same statement.

You can do this instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) - COUNT(Distinct Name) FROM Highschooler
```